# react native ios release mode image not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

in debug mode , local image showing but in release mode local image not showing

react 17.0.2,
react-native 0.67.4
xcode 14.2 and 14.3
iphone simulator 12 and 14 pro

the code is

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image } from "react-native";

const img =  "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/painting-mountain-lake-with-mountain-background_188544-9126.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.1.87170709.1707350400&semt=sph";

const img2 = require("./nature_wallpaper.jpg");

const App2 = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>App2</Text>
      <Image style={{ height: "30%", width: "50%" }} source={{ uri: img }} />
      <Image
        style={{ height: "30%", width: "50%", marginTop: 20 }}
        source={img2}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App2;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

network image loading properly but local image not loading

xcode console says like this
`[native] Could not find image file:///Users/dev123/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4AA32123-5CE9-4ABC-BB2C-5D5FF12360A0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/13E88-B1E9-A2A2-B9D8-43DB27A9B27/TestApp1.app/assets/nature_wallpaper.jpg`

i have tried bundling asset, added jsbundle in build phase,  and added asset folder to the project

but still facing the issue. i have been struggiling for the past 2 days.

Comment: Please try to rewrite the first sentence to make it a full sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In Release mode, the application often runs from a different location and file paths can change. You may need to use dynamic paths to access the image. I don't know since you haven't shared the code. Be especially careful when finding the file path.

Comment: hi i have edited the question with code FYI